# Find an equation for a sphere where a spherical polygon was removed

Tags: geometry

My objective is the following: I know the parameters of a 3d sphere S, e.g. radius and center, and I know a set of points E on the sphere which forms a polygon. I need to find an eq. which describes all points inside this spherical polygon. I'm very unsure what the best way would be to proceed.

Edit: Application if this would be available:
Triangulate the sphere surface without the spherical polygon and stop at the polygon's edges.

Edit: Not necessarily it needs to be an equation. A strategy would be also useful.

Comment: What does "hole" have to do with this question?

Comment: This doesn't solve your problem, but the proper term is "spherical polygon".

Comment: David: I want a description/eq. of a sphere where a spherical polygon was removed

Comment: Then I suggest you ask *that* question instead of the one you did.

Comment: David: Thank you. See my edit.

Comment: I'm not sure what an "equation" for points outside the spherical polygon would look like.  The corresponding problem for a polygon in the plane would describe points outside a polygon.  Even in the "nice" case of a convex polygon, the easiest way to describe those points would be a system of (linear) inequalities.  Perhaps you should describe how you would apply this equation if it were available, so Readers can address the intended application.

Comment: I suggest you begin by thinking through the cases of a small number of points.  Even with three points it is unclear how you decide which region is "inside" the spherical polygon and which region is "outside".  All that an objective observer could tell is that the three distinct points determine a boundary that splits the spherical surface into two components.  With four points it will not even be obvious what boundary is intended.  Consider the equivalent problem in the plane, where the same four points may be vertices of more than one nonconvex quadrilateral.

Comment: ok i will try this.  it seems this is a non trivial problem?